# Set Datasource on client machine in Crystal Report

Tags: vb.net, crystal-reports

I have created crystal report in vb 2008, I have added database (access). Its working fine in my computer.

When i tried to run from my other computer, crystal report prompt to login, But i checked integrated security, but i was not able to change database path, its disabled.

Is there any way i can change my database path like i am using in windows form like `"Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=|DataDirectory|\\Database1.mdb;Persist Security Info=False"` in crystal report as well?

Answer (score 1):

You need to apply the logon info at runtime before showing the report.

```
Dim crtablelogoninfos New TableLogOnInfos()
Dim crtablelogoninfo  New TableLogOnInfo()

crconnectioninfo.ServerName = "\\server\d\AppFolder\db.mdb"
crconnectioninfo.DatabaseName = String.Empty
crconnectioninfo.UserID = "Admin"
crconnectioninfo.Password = String.Empty

cryrpt.Load(_reportPath)

For Each CrTable As CrystalDecisions.CrystalReports.Engine.Table in cryrpt.Database.Tables
{
    crtablelogoninfo = CrTable.LogOnInfo
    crtablelogoninfo.ConnectionInfo = crconnectioninfo
    CrTable.ApplyLogOnInfo(crtablelogoninfo)
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply, want to ask, i have already created design in Crystal report by dragging database field to report, Whether this code will affect my design in crystal report?? because in my crystal report still showing database as "d:/database1.mdb

Comment: nop.. it will just map the path and database connection to ur crystal report. so, CR can retrieve the data from connected database.